# How to style items in the ItemsPresenter of a custom ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, itemspresenter

I am trying to create a custom ItemsControl, which shows RadioButtons or Checkboxes and applies styles to those items automatically.

This is what I have right now:

Custom ItemsControl:

```
public class LabelContainer : ItemsControl
{
    public string Label
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string),
   typeof(LabelContainer), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

Styles:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<Style TargetType="local:LabelContainer">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LabelContainer">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Margin="0,0,7,6" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"/>
                    <ItemsPresenter>
                        <ItemsPresenter.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0"/>
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsPresenter.Resources>
                    </ItemsPresenter>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I am using it like this:

```
<local:LabelContainer Label="RadioButtons:">
    <RadioButton>Nr 1</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton>Nr 2</RadioButton>
</local:LabelContainer>
```

Everything is working fine, except styling the individual items. In this case I am trying to add a margin to the radiobuttons. I am aware I could add the margins to each and every item manually, but I'm trying to avoid this.

I have tried putting the styles in ItemsPresenter.Resources of the main style and I have tried putting it in StackPanel.Resources of the ItemsPanelTemplate. Both of those options are not working, the styles are not applied.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: I had to put the styles for the RadioButtons and CheckBoxes in the Style.Resources of the custom ItemsControl.

This is the working code:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<Style TargetType="local:LabelContainer">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LabelContainer">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Margin="0,0,7,6" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"/>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type RadioButton}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```